# R - Why does sapply return lists within this dataframe when searching for values in another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I have the following two 2 data.frames:

**df1**

```
structure(list(thread_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), course_week = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), user_id = c(1237305, 3001241, 1237305, 1237305, 
4455134, 4398594), post_id_unique = c("1-NA", "1-post-1", "2-NA", 
"2-post-2", "2-post-2", "2-post-2"), to = list(NULL, 1L, NULL, 
    2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("thread_id", "course_week", "user_id", 
"post_id_unique", "to"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**df2**

```
structure(list(thread_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), course_week = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), user_id = c(1237305, 3001241, 1237305, 1237305, 
4455134, 4398594), post_id_unique = c("1-post-1", "1-post-1125", 
"2-post-2", "2-post-3", "2-post-43", "2-post-54")), .Names = c("thread_id", 
"course_week", "user_id", "post_id_unique"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to replace **df1$to** with the value in **df2$user_id** that matches the **$post_id_unique** column in both files.

I've made the following code for it:

```
from <- as.list(df1$post_id_unique)
replace <- function(i){if(grepl("NA",i)!=TRUE) {df2[df2$post_id_unique==i,1]}}
df1$to <- sapply(from, replace)
```

Which works almost perfectly... except that every value within **df1$to** is a list rather than a numeric or character vector:

```
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ thread_id     : int  1 1 2 2 2 2
 $ course_week   : num  1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ user_id       : num  1237305 3001241 1237305 1237305 4455134 ...
 $ post_id_unique: chr  "1-NA" "1-post-1" "2-NA" "2-post-2" ...
 $ to            :List of 6
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : int 1
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : int 2
  ..$ : int 2
  ..$ : int 2
```

Why is my original code creating lists within the dataframe? How can I unlist them? Or avoid them to start with.

I know this is similar to a merge(), but I am interested in doing it this way for learning and other reasons.

Comment: You should include sample data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (ideally a `dput`). It sounds like you just want a `merge()`. You should provide the desired output for the problem data.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @MrFlick. I had already tried the merge function and it was returning a data.frame with less rows than the original DF (I guess because there are repeated values). Besides that I am interested in learning how to use sapply. Do you think its not efficient/effective ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is that sometimes your `replace()` function doesn't return a value (when the `i` value contains "NA"). Since `sapply` always returns an object with the same length as the input, NULL values are returned for the function. NULLs cannot be placed in a simple vector, so the result of sapply is cast to a list. you can fix this by returning a NA instead of nothing

```
replace <- function(i){if(grepl("NA",i)!=TRUE) {df2[df2$post_id_unique==i,1]} else {NA}}
```

But really it looks like you are doing a basic left merge operation. The basic syntax would be

```
merge(df1, df2, by="post_id_unique", all.x=T)
```

Comment: You are right, it is a basic left merge operation, it is a better way to solve it that way. 

Thanks!